# Spring security SAML : Which lib to create an Identity provider to connect to service provider

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-security-saml2

I want to create an identityprovider to authenticate to an sso server using Spring security saml2. Can I create an ID using the 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-saml2-service-provider' library or should I do this using 'org.springframework.security.extensions: spring-security-saml:1.0.10.RELEASE' or 'org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:2.0.0.M31'

I have the impression that the documentation is mainly around setting up service providers

Comment: Its described here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/overview.html#servlet-saml2login-minimaldependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to your question I want to say that

```
org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:2.0.0.M31
```

and

```
org.springframework.security.extensions:%20spring-security-saml%3A1.0.10.RELEASE
```

Were removed from support more details you will be able to find [spring-security-saml-extensions-1-x-eol-on-october-6-2021](https://spring.io/blog/2020/09/22/spring-security-saml-extensions-1-x-eol-on-october-6-2021)

It could also be seeing into [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.extensions/spring-security-saml)

Based on it you have to use

```
org.springframework.security:spring-security-saml2-service-provider
```

That is currently maintained you can check it also on [maven central repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-saml2-service-provider)

Also a reference to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/index.html)